# "on my way home last night" / "last night, on my way home"

Tags: sentence-construction

If I understand right, both versions are idiomatic and often used. There is no difference in their meaning. From English grammar view, the first sentence is more typical because "where?" (on my way home) is used before "when?" (last night). Right?

> The police stopped me **on my way home last night**.
>
> The police stopped me **last night, on my way home**.

If the second example sounds good, could I say the following:

> The police stopped her car **in Paris last night**.
>
> The police stopped her car **last night, in Paris**.

Comment: The order in which you say it depends on which seems more significant to you - when it happened, or what you were doing at the time.

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326826/on-my-way-home-last-night-last-night-on-my-way-home#comment616253_326826) user [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers) gave the following answer:

> In your examples there's no real scope for ambiguity, regardless of the sequence and punctuation of ***multiple adverbial elements***. But consider
>
> 1. *The police stopped me **in a sports car last night***
> 2. *The police stopped me **last night in a sports car***.
>
> I think there's always *some* ambiguity there (who was driving the sports car?), but for my money it's more likely the police in #1 and me in #2. Of course, if we replace ***sports car*** with ***panda car***, the *semantics* (not *syntax*) would change a bit.

Comment: Please show me where is an answer on my question/post here?